# Designing influxDB schema

Tags: nosql, influxdb

I work on a project where I have multiple measuring devices (with various types of sensors on one measuring device) in multiple locations.

I am using influxDB v2.1 and I desing my bucket where I am writing data into _measurements.

```
Location(tag)| Device(tag)|   _field    |
-------------|------------|-------------|
location A   | device1    |device1_temp |
location B   | device2    |device1_press| 
...
```

So now If I want to delete **device1_temp** from _field this is no longer available in version 2. So this Query **will not work**

```
influx delete --bucket db --start 2022-05-04T00:00:00Z --stop 2022-05-06T00:00:00Z --predicate '_measurement="sensors" AND _field="device1_temp"'
```

Instead of this query I have to delete data **by tag**

```
influx delete --bucket db --start 2022-05-04T00:00:00Z --stop 2022-05-06T00:00:00Z --predicate '_measurement="sensors" AND device="device1"'
```

**BUT this will delete all measurements from other sensors installed on this device1**

My question is what is the best approach to be able to delete exact measurements from device sensor's. What is the best approach to design influxDB v2 bucket schema?

I know about **retention policy** and this bucket has persistent data so no retention policy is applied.